# How to get Google map Markers from URLs using asynctask?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

I am trying to get Markers from URL. What I want is get all Markers from [this web service](https://www.towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=all_products).

My code is not working. It is getting map_icon from the web service but not showing on the map. What can I do to make it work?

**Log message:**

```
 E/pj: http://towncitycards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/googlemapicons/5percent.png
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 78.773ms
 E/addMarkers: 0
 W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity.addMarkers(Frnt_mapActivity.java:299)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity.access$300(Frnt_mapActivity.java:73)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity$Frnt_mIcons_Activity.onPostExecute(Frnt_mapActivity.java:428)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity$Frnt_mIcons_Activity.onPostExecute(Frnt_mapActivity.java:332)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 E/pj: http://towncitycards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/googlemapicons/save£2.png
 E/addMarkers: 1
 W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity.addMarkers(Frnt_mapActivity.java:299)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity.access$300(Frnt_mapActivity.java:73)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity$Frnt_mIcons_Activity.onPostExecute(Frnt_mapActivity.java:428)
 W/System.err:     at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity$Frnt_mIcons_Activity.onPostExecute(Frnt_mapActivity.java:332)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**My code**

```
public class Frnt_mapActivity extends Activity {

public String Shop_title;
public String Shop_address;
public String Shop_icons;
ProgressDialog mDialog;
JSONObject jsonobject3;
JSONArray jsonarray3;
 // Google Map
private static GoogleMap googlemap;

ArrayList<SearchBeams>getAllimgs;
// Location
ArrayList<String> world_locationlist;
ArrayList<LocationBeams> worldlocation;
// Looking for
ArrayList<String> looking_forlist;
ArrayList<LookingForBeams> world_looking_for;

public static ArrayList<SearchBeams> searchdata_list;
public static ArrayList<NormalSearchBeams> normlSearchList;
public static String mid; 
public static String mpost_title; 
public static String mimage;    
public static List<String> imglist;

ArrayList<All_products_lat_long> venueList;

RelativeLayout r1;
public static ArrayList<SearchBeams> GetIMG;
public static TextView txtlocation;
public static TextView txtlookingfor;

public static ArrayList<All_products_lat_long> mpItm;
String vals;


private int i;
private Intent intent;
HashMap<Marker, Integer> hashMap=new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();
public static LatLng latlong ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frnt_map_activity);

    googlemap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.places_map)).getMap();
    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    intent=new Intent(Frnt_mapActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    googlemap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
             i=hashMap.get(arg0);
                intent.putExtra("PRODUCT_ID", venueList.get(i).getId());
                startActivity(intent);
                //overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_left );
        }
    });


    new Frnt_mIcons_Activity().execute();


}
private void addMarkers() {

        for(int k=0; k<venueList.size(); k += 1){

            //nirmal
            try{
                Log.e("pj",venueList.get(k).getMap_icon());

                //new AddMarkerAsyncTask(venueList.get(k),k).execute();

                double ln = Double.parseDouble(venueList.get(k).getLongitude());
                double la = Double.parseDouble(venueList.get(k).getLatitude());
                String title=venueList.get(k).getPost_title()==null?"":venueList.get(k).getPost_title();
                URL url = new URL(venueList.get(k).getMap_icon());
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                BitmapDescriptor bd=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image);

                Marker marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                        .title(title)
                        .icon(bd));
                hashMap.put(marker, k);

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("addMarkers",k+"");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        }

/******************FOR MAP******************/
class Frnt_mIcons_Activity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public ArrayList<All_products_lat_long> maplist;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(Frnt_mapActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }




    // Slow Implementation
    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String s = "";
        String line = "";
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                s += line; 
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return s;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        maplist = new ArrayList<All_products_lat_long>();

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

// Set verifier
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=all_products");

        try{

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            jsonobject3 = new JSONObject(data);
            jsonarray3 = new JSONArray(jsonobject3.getString("all_products"));
            venueList =new ArrayList<All_products_lat_long>();
            for(int j=0; j<jsonarray3.length();j++){
                JSONObject itemobj = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(j);
                //SHOW SEARCH RESULT
                All_products_lat_long searchItems = new All_products_lat_long();

                searchItems.setId(itemobj.getString("ID"));
                searchItems.setPost_title(itemobj.getString("post_title"));
                searchItems.setMap_icon(itemobj.getString("map_icon"));
                searchItems.setLongitude(itemobj.getString("longitude"));
                searchItems.setLatitude(itemobj.getString("latitude"));
    //          System.out.println("######Ashish is object >>"+itemobj);
                venueList.add(searchItems);
    //      System.out.println("SEARCHLISTSS@@@@@@@"+venueList.get(j).getLongitude());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //System.out.println("SEARCHLISTSS@@@@@@@"+venueList);
        //System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+venueList);
        try{
            if(venueList.size()>0)
            {
            addMarkers();
        //Toast.makeText(Frnt_mapActivity.this,"Search for the venue11.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            Toast.makeText(Frnt_mapActivity.this,"Search for the venue.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(22.75852160, 75.8911550);
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(50.85514, 0.58382);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 18);
            googlemap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray3.length(); i++) {

                jsonobject3 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(i);

                Shop_title = jsonobject3.optString("post_title");
                Shop_address = jsonobject3.optString("map_icon");
                Shop_icons = jsonobject3.optString("map_icon");     
                        //}
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()){
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Seems like the request is being blocked, I suggest looking into android security policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

in your `onPostExecute()` move your Json parsing code to `doInBackground`

Now in `addMarkers()` method use `picasso` to load the marker image and use the bitmap.

```
 private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
           //here you get the image bitmap 
           //do your work
      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}
```

call it using:

```
  Picasso.with(this).load("your_url").into(target);
```

in gradle add: `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Comment: for multiple url what can I do

Comment: call this `Picasso.with(this).load("your_url").into(target);` in the for loop..you are already using it. Remove network calls in your `addMarkers()` function and use picasso